Concourse CI : Default Values fo Variables in YAML File
In Concourse YAML File, I defined variables and their values or placeholder.
How do we assign a default if the value is not being passed in the command line ?
YAML File Snippet :
input_info: &inputInfo
  ABC: ((input-abc))


jobs:
  - name: update-pipeline
    plan:
      - task: task1
        .
        .
        params:
           <<: [ *inputInfo ]

If I pass the 'input-abc' in the fly command line its all good, but If I dont pass the 'input-abc', I want to assign some default value.
Getting the below errors in the pipelines now :
failed to interpolate task config: undefined vars: input-abc
